# What is a word meaning "an oft used cliché or line used to defend oneself from negative criticism"?

Tags: vocabulary

For example, when someone is being told that  they're being a prick, they might trot out the old, "I'm just saying it like it is. You all can't handle this real talk!", as if that excuses their bad behaviour. What is a word for such lines; lame clichéd defenses of negative aspects of something or someone?

Comment: I don't really understand your context. The idiom is ***tell** it like it is,* (not ***say***), but are you asking about situations where a person defends himself by saying he's "only being honest, telling the truth" when in fact he's *lying*? Or do you mean a situation where what the person is saying really is true? (But other people don't wish to hear his particular truth, because it's inconvenient, embarrassing, or whatever.) In that latter case, perhaps he's ***insensitive***.

Comment: Ah, sorry no that doesn't answer it. Let me clarify. The word I'm looking for is a noun, a type of statement. A statement that is trotted out as a standard defence against an attack on someone's character. But this statement isn't really a legitimate justification of whatever actions are causing said person's character to be called into question.

Comment: @JishnuJairaj: Your post seems to assume that there _is_ such a word. Is that the case? Have you heard/read this word being used? Or are you trying to find out if such a word exists? (In which case, an edit is in order.)

Comment: @Jishnu, you haven't answered *my* question. In what circumstances do you consider that claiming to be telling the truth is *not* a "legitimate justification"?

Comment: Trying to find out if such a word exists. What do I need to edit?

Comment: You need to edit at least enough to clarify exactly what kind of situation you're trying to describe.

Comment: So to take a hypothetical example, suppose a guy gets rejected by a girl and he gets mad and does something really irrational. He might later try to defend it saying, "I was mad. It wasn't my fault." But of course, that doesn't really justify his actions.

Comment: Blame shifting? Passing the buck? These terms refer to the type of negative behaviour used, rather than the form of statement used to excuse it.

Answer (score 1):

A **platitude** is a trite or cliche saying, but it does not typically have the connotation that it is uttered to excuse an inconsistent, illogical, or outdated position as "true but politically incorrect," which is I think what you're hearing.

I like using the phrase **"the last refuge"** to describe a position that someone holds by virtue of their inability to understand anything else. It's seen a couple different uses, and you can adapt it to fit your needs.

*Patriotism is the last refuge of the scoundrel.* -Samuel Johnson

*Violence is the last refuge of the incompetent.* -Isaac Asimov

*Consistency is the last refuge of the unimaginitive.* -Oscar Wilde

^All the above quotations are from the internet, and therefore likely actually uttered by Michael Scott, and not the person referenced.

Nevertheless, I feel like you could adapt your own *bon mot* to suit your needs.  Perhaps,

> Political incorrectness is the last refuge of the outdated.

or

> Such excuses are the last refuge of the spiteful.

Or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for this, this is quite helpful. I guess,  ultimately, what I'm looking for is a word that describes a clichéd and pathetic/flimsy excuse for one's bad behaviour or actions.

Answer (score 1):

> **rationalize**
>
> *verb*
>
> Attempt to explain or justify (one’s own or another’s behavior or
>   attitude) with logical, plausible reasons, even if these are not true
>   or appropriate:
>   *she couldn’t rationalize her urge to return to the cottage*
> <sub>[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rationalize)</sub>

**rationalization**

*noun*

> **Rationalization (making excuses)**
>
> In psychology and logic, rationalization or rationalisation (also
>   known as making excuses) is a defense mechanism in which controversial
>   behaviors or feelings are justified and explained in a seemingly
>   rational or logical manner to avoid the true explanation, and are made
>   consciously tolerable – or even admirable and superior – by plausible
>   means. It is also an informal fallacy of reasoning. Rationalisation
>   happens in two steps:
>
> 1. A decision, action, judgement is made for a given reason, or no (known) reason at all (in cases for instance of dogmatic judgement or
>      normal behaviour).
> 2. A rationalisation is performed, constructing a seemingly good or logical reason, as an attempt to justify the act after the fact (for
>      oneself or others).
>
> Rationalization encourages irrational or unacceptable behavior,
>   motives, or feelings and often involves ad hoc hypothesizing. This
>   process ranges from fully conscious (e.g. to present an external
>   defense against ridicule from others) to mostly unconscious (e.g. to
>   create a block against internal feelings of guilt). People rationalize
>   for various reasons — sometimes when we think we know ourselves better
>   than we do. Rationalization may differentiate the original
>   deterministic explanation of the behavior or feeling in
>   question.
> <sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalization_(making_excuses))</sub>

Comment: Ah yes, so  a popular statement used to rationalize bad behaviour and protect oneself from external  ridicule. Is there a word for something like that? I wouldn't be surprised if there wasn't. Just curious to know whether there is.

Comment: @JishnuJairaj - Some rationalizations are very common, though I don't know a specific term for them, I'd say "common rationalizations" see http://community.aiim.org/blogs/steve-weissman/2012/07/18/5-common-rationalizations-for-organizational-inertia

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like a quip? The dictionary definition does not quite give the connotation I associate with it.

Comment: I think "quip" is rather the opposite of what OP is looking for.